# How to fix Solidity version missmatch from Visual Studio Code

Tags: solidity, visual-studio-code

So I have install the Solidity extension for Visual Studio.

V0.0.76
https://github.com/juanfranblanco/vscode-solidity

And when I start my Solidity code with

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
```

I get the following error in visual studio.

Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.7.0+commit.9e61f92b.Emscripten.clang) - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version

However I'm using truffle to compile and when I run truffle version I get

```
Truffle v5.0.2 (core: 5.0.2)
Solidity v0.5.0 (solc-js)
Node v12.16.3
```

So my code is compiling but I would like to know how to specify the solidity version to visual code as well to prevent error warning.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Right click on the error, and change workspace compiler seems work.
[image: Right click o]

Comment: Il give it to you! Please up vote the question

Comment: @MadeInDreams thanks man, i want to comment your answer but cannot insert image

Comment: It`s all good it's better this way!

Comment: Still not working for me :(

Answer (score 3):

If you still have a problem with the version in VS Code, this worked for me:

Install specific `solc` version locally or globally: `npm i -g solc` or `npm i solc`.

Add this setting in local VSCode settings: `.vscode/settings.json`

```
{
    "solidity.compileUsingRemoteVersion": "v0.7.4+commit.3f05b770",
    "solidity.enableLocalNodeCompiler": false
}
```

In my case I am using `solidity v0.7.4`. Note also the other config: `"solidity.enableLocalNodeCompiler": false`